# Calculate date based on pattern from anchor date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have a rolling 4 week (28 day) date pattern starting from an anchor date in the past. I need to know what the nearest previous pattern start date is relative to the current date.

For example:

Anchor date = Monday June 30 2013. If today's date is August 7 2013 then the date I would like returned is July 29 2013. Previous pattern start dates were June 30, July 29. The next pattern start date is August 26 but that is after today's date of August 7 2013.

Hope that makes sense and thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused -- if the anchor data is June 30th, shouldn't the next date be July 28th (and then August 25) -- 28 days later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not 100% sure I understand where July 29th comes from, if you want to retrieve the closest date 28 days from an anchor date, one way would be to use a recursive CTE (although it could have a performance implication).

```
declare @anchor datetime
set @anchor = '6/30/2013'

;with cte as (
  select @anchor dt
  union all 
  select dateadd(day, 28, dt) dt
  from cte
  where dt <= dateadd(day, -28, '8/7/2013')
)
select max(dt) from cte
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18400)

---

Perhaps an even simpler solution would be to use `datediff` as well:

```
declare @anchor datetime
set @anchor = '6/30/2013'

select dateadd(day, 28 * (datediff(day, @anchor, getDate())/28), @anchor)
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18418)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer before posting essentially the same solution. I will +1 your answer as it was the earliest one.

Answer (score 0):

I think your calculation is a little off. 28 days after 30/Jun in 28/Jul then 25/Aug.
Anyways, here is my query which will return 28/Jul, which I believe to be the correct answer.

```
WITH my_date AS
   (SELECT CAST('30/Jun/2013' AS DATETIME)AS the_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(day,28,the_date)AS the_date
    FROM my_date
    WHERE my_date.the_date <= dateadd(day,-28,getdate())
    )
SELECT max(the_date)
FROM my_date
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/6267